# How can I bindkey ctrl-left to word-left?

Tags: tcsh

I use tcsh and emacs. In emacs, I'm used to the ctrl-left bindkey moving me left by a word. I'd like to do the same thing in my tcsh terminal.

I can do ctrl-b, but I'm just not used to it.

It's not clear to me from the bindkey manpath how to specify the ctrl-left key combination.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 11):

Google answers all (if you look deep enough).

```
bindkey '^[[1;5D'   backward-word           # ctrl+left
bindkey '^[[1;5C'   forward-word            # ctrl+right
```

From Google's cache of http://lofotenmoose.info/bsd/conf/amd64/tcshrc-root.

This works for tcsh 6.13.00