# set commandline shortcut in tcsh for moving cursor by word

Tags: command-line, cursor, move, shortcut, tcsh

from [How to move the cursor by word in command line of tcsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089573/how-to-move-the-cursor-by-word-in-command-line-of-tcsh) I know how to move cursor by word in tcsh, but they not easy to use, so can I set a shortcut on command line for example, when I use Ctrl+leftarrow, it actually works as Esc f?

Comment: Try these: http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/data-services/linux_basics/tcsh

Comment: Hey, thanks. Just first type Esc, then type f, feels  like strange. would be nice like in bash, Ctrl+f for moving by word. It's a shell on the server not easy to change. Big thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see a list of pre-defined key-bindings, visit:

http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/data-services/linux_basics/tcsh

To see a list of all commands which can be used to configure key-bindings, visit:

http://www.rohidekar.com/sridharsarnobat/mediawiki/index.php?title=TCSH_Key_bindings

Example: (Write this in your ~/.tcshrc)

```
bindkey '^[^[[C' forward-word
bindkey '^[^[[D' backward-word
```

This will bind the alt-right with forward-word and alt-left with backword-word.

To map to a different keyset, just run `cat` and hit enter. Hit the key-combination (in the above example, right-arrow and left-arrow), record the strings that are echoed back, and use these as the key combinations to bind.

Comment: thanks! there is also a thread here that I didn't know before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099507/how-can-i-bindkey-ctrl-left-to-word-left